# How to list entries related to a category + related to a section?

Tags: entries, categories, relations

Sorry if this has been asked before. I've searched for other relatedTo questions but could not find anything similar.

I have 2 sections (each having 1 entry type):

- games
- reviews

Games are linked to 1 or more categories using a Categories field.
Reviews are linked to 1 or more games using an Entries field.

On a category page I can list all related games using:

```
craft.entries({section: 'games'}).relatedTo(category)
```

I do however want to list all games inside a category that have at least 1 review. I tried something like

```
craft.entries({section: 'games'}).relatedTo(category).relatedTo(craft.entries.section('reviews'))
```

but that lists all games having a review regardless of the category. How to solve this?

Comment: Think I found the answer myself already. Maybe someone can confirm this is indeed the best way?

    {% paginate
        craft.entries({section: 'games'})
            .relatedTo(
                'and',
                category,
                {sourceElement: craft.entries({section: 'reviews'}), field: 'games'}
            )
            .limit(8)
        as games
    %}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you call this:

```twig
craft.entries({section: 'games'}).relatedTo(category).relatedTo(craft.entries.section('reviews'))
```

that second `relatedTo` param is just overriding the first one. Lucky for you, that parameter does accept multiple criteria (see the “Passing Multiple Relation Criteria” section on http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param).

```twig
{% set games = craft.entries({
    section: 'games',
    relatedTo: ['and',
        category,
        craft.entries.section('reviews').status(null)
    ]
}) %}
```

It's a good idea to specify that `category` will be a *target* element (where the Games entries did the selecting), and that the Reviews will be *source* elements (where the Games were selected by the Reviews), as this will slim the DB query down a bit:

```twig
{% set games = craft.entries({
    section: 'games',
    relatedTo: ['and',
        { targetElement: category },
        { sourceElement: craft.entries.section('reviews').status(null) }
    ]
}) %}
```

Comment: Good to know that this is possible, Brandon! Thanks also for the advise to use targetElement / sourceElement to slim down the DB query. Does it make sense to also include the field handle in the parameter to further reduce the load?

Comment: Specifying the field handle won’t have much of an effect; it’s only necessary if you have more than one relational field between the elements and you want to filter the results to just pay attention to a particular field.

Comment: I get a template error using the syntax above. Think it should be relatedTo: [...]  ?

Comment: Sorry, yes. Fixed.

Comment: In 2022, chaining multiple .relatedTo works as expected, like an AND.